# How do I fix cfWheels ERROR: Wheels.TableNotFound?

Tags: model-view-controller, runtime-error, crud, cfwheels

I am new to Cfwheels and MVC.  Cfwheels website is up and running.
I have successfully completed https://guides.cfwheels.org/docs/beginner-tutorial-hello-world .
Now I am trying to just test the cfwheels to mySql database connection.  I have NO tables in the mySql database.

The error I get is;

> Wheels.TableNotFound ttt_shows table could not be found in the
>   database.
>
> Suggested action
>
> Add a table named ttt_shows to your database or tell CFWheels to use a
>   different table for this model. For example you can tell a user model
>   to use a table called tbl_users by creating a User.cfc file in the
>   models folder, creating an init method inside it and then calling
>   table("tbl_users") from within it.
>
> The ttt_shows table could not be found in the database.
>   < 
>   Error location: Line 4 in views\ttt_show\cf_info_mysql.cfm ;
>
> ```
> <cfset mySqlVerStruct= model("ttt_show").getMySqlVersion1() />
> ```
>
> Tag context;
>
> Error thrown on line 169 in wheels\model\adapters\Base.cfc
>    called from line 72 in wheels\model\initialization.cfm
>    called from line 1 in root.cfm
>    called from line 576 in wheels\global\internal.cfm
>    called from line 861 in wheels\global\internal.cfm
>    called from line 164 in wheels\global\cfml.cfm
>    called from line 14 in wheels\global\cfml.cfm
>    called from line 206 in wheels\global\public.cfm
>    called from line 4 in views\ttt_show\cf_info_mysql.cfm
>    called from line 128 in wheels\global\cfml.cfm
>    called from line 434 in wheels\controller\rendering.cfm
>    called from line 157 in wheels\controller\rendering.cfm
>    called from line 53 in wheels\controller\rendering.cfm
>    called from line 141 in wheels\controller\processing.cfm
>    called from line 95 in wheels\controller\processing.cfm
>    called from line 198 in wheels\dispatch\request.cfm
>    called from line 1 in wheels\index.cfm
>    called from line 1 in index.cfm
>    called from line 1 in wheels\events\onrequest.cfm

---

Note: A related/subpart of my question is; In CfWheels, how do I create a model that does not have an associated database table?  In the future I will need to code a model that does not have a database attached - but does CRUD operations against an xml or json file.
Thanks in advance for any help / guidance.

---

So far I have the following code;

```html
<!--- FILE: ..\views\ttt_show.cfm --->
<h1>MySql Version Query using;  model("ttt_show").getMySqlVersion1() </h1>

<cfset mySqlVerStruct= model("ttt_show").getMySqlVersion1() />

<cfdump var="#mySqlVerStruct#" label="MySql version" />
```

```html
<cfcomponent extends="Model">
  <!--- FILE: ..\models\ttt_show.cfc --->
  <cffunction name="init">
  </cffunction>

  <!--- - -   getMySqlVersion1()  - - --->
  <cffunction name="getMySqlVersion1">
    <!--- USED BY ..\views\ttt_show\cf_info_mysql.cfm --->
    <cfset retStruct=S tructNew( "qryMySqlVersion1") />
    <cfset retStruct.errorStr="" />
    <cfset retStruct.datasource="#get('dataSourceName')#" />
    <cfset retStruct.username="#get('dataSourceUserName')#" />
    <cfset retStruct.password="#get('dataSourcePassword')#" />
    <cfset retStruct.qry="" />
    <cfreturn retStruct>
  </cffunction>

  <!--- - -   getMySqlVersion2()  - - --->
  <cffunction name="getMySqlVersion2">
    <!--- USED BY ..\views\ttt_show\cf_info_mysql.cfm --->
    <cfquery name="MySqlVersion2" debug="no" datasource="#APPLICATION.wheels.DATASOURCENAME#" timeout="5">
      select version() as mysql_version
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn MySqlVersion2>
  </cffunction>

  <!--- - -   Create...Table()  - - --->
  <cffunction name="createEmptyTable">
    <cfquery result="myCreateTblResults" datasource="#get('dataSourceName')#">
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_masters` ( `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'unique primary key id', `textValue` varchar(255) default NULL COMMENT 'any text value', `numValue` int(11) default NULL COMMENT 'any numeric value', `dtValue`
      datetime default NULL COMMENT 'any datetime value', `recStatus` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1' COMMENT 'Status of This Record', `dtCreated` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'date that record was created', PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
      COMMENT='Stores any general key/value pairs for app, MASTER in master-slaves relationship';
    </cfquery>

    <!--- return false: error: not tested yet --->
    <cfreturn false>
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

```html
<cfcomponent extends="Controller"><!--- FILE: ..\controllers\ttt_show.cfc --->
    
 <!--- 
 --- Show debug info / or test a '..\view\*.cfm file.
 --->

 <!--- SEE ..\views\ttt_show\cf_info_mysql.cfm --->
    <cffunction name="cf_info_mysql"> 
    </cffunction>    
    
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading further, I found out the general answer (but have not tested code yet).

At https://guides.cfwheels.org/docs/object-relational-mapping under the heading; "Models Without Database Tables",  documentation explains that in your model/*.cfm file, you need to add;

```
function config() {
  table(false);
  }
```

From the document;

> "With that in place, you have the foundation for a model that never
>   touches the database. When you call methods like save(), create(),
>   update(), and delete() on a tableless model, the entire model
>   lifecycle will still run, including object validation and object
>   callbacks."

Now if I can just find a source code example of this type of model.

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't just create the table in the database? Tableless models are a different use case really, and more designed for forms etc..